# How to increment at different intervals python?

Tags: python, ip-address

Say I had an IP address `192.168.1.1`
How would I increment at different intervals like this?

```
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

... and all the way to `192.168.1.999` then "roll over" to `192.168.2.1` ?

Comment: @MoxieBall it was just an example

Comment: How are you storing this IP address?

Comment: @JacobBoertjes as a string

Comment: Do you want a function that takes an ip string and an interval and increments the ip by that much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ip3 in range(1, 127):
    for ip4 in range(1, 999):
        ip = '.'.join("192", "68", str(ip3), str(ip4))
```

Will that give you the idea?

Comment: While this answers the exact question, this produces a number of invalid IP addresses.

Comment: @MatthewStory I have something that handles that, thanks for the comment anyways.

Comment: @MatthewStory: I realize that; OP was looking for an incrementation solution.  I'm assuming he knows how to handle IP limitations -- and thanks for highlighting the potential problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the stdlib [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) for this. Don't attempt to do it with raw string manipulation, because there are several gotchas and weird edge-cases.  Using the object-oriented libraries will protect you from generating invalid data.

To iterate the ipv4 addresses from 192.168.1.0 through to 192.168.1.255, inclusive, is equivalent to iterate the 192.168.1.0/24 [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork).  Use a [network](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#network-objects) object:

```
>>> from ipaddress import ip_network
>>> list(ip_network('192.168.1.0/24'))
[IPv4Address('192.168.1.0'),
 IPv4Address('192.168.1.1'),
 IPv4Address('192.168.1.2'),
...
 IPv4Address('192.168.1.255')]
```

Some of these addresses are not usable hosts, for example the 255 is a [broadcast address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address).  Iterate the [hosts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network.hosts) instead if that's what you're looking for:

```
>>>> list(ip_network('192.168.1.0/24').hosts())
[IPv4Address('192.168.1.1'),
 IPv4Address('192.168.1.2'),
 IPv4Address('192.168.1.3'),
...
 IPv4Address('192.168.1.254')]
```

Note that 192.168.1.999 is not a valid ip address, so don't generate that!  The validator will prevent you creating it anyway:

```
>>> from ipaddress import ip_address
>>> ip_address('192.168.1.254')
IPv4Address('192.168.1.254')
>>> ip_address('192.168.1.999')
# ValueError: '192.168.1.999' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
```

To convert from an [ip address object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_address) back to a plain old string, just call `str` on it.

Your question also asked about "rolling over" to 192.168.2.1.  This is just iterating a different subnet. The 24 in 192.168.1.0/24 refers to 24 significant bits allocated for the network prefix (the remaining 8 bits reserved for host addressing), i.e. the *subnet mask* 255.255.255.0.

To make it "rollover", you really just want to iterate a bigger subnet:

```
>>> gen = iter(ip_network('192.168.0.0/16'))
>>> for i in range(255*2):
...     next(gen)
...     
>>> next(gen)
IPv4Address('192.168.1.254')
>>> next(gen)
IPv4Address('192.168.1.255')
>>> next(gen)
IPv4Address('192.168.2.0')
>>> next(gen)
IPv4Address('192.168.2.1')
```

To get from a single ip address string to the network object, you can use the [`supernet`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network.supernet) method:

```
>>> from ipaddress import ip_address, ip_interface
>>> ip = ip_address('192.168.1.1')
>>> net = ip_interface(ip).network
>>> net
IPv4Network('192.168.1.1/32')
>>> net.supernet(prefixlen_diff=8)
IPv4Network('192.168.1.0/24')
```

Read about [Internet Protocol version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) for more info, and the official docs for Python's [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

```
# for IP addresses of the form 1.92.168.a.b

a_max = 10
b_max = 999

ips = []
for a in range(a_max):
    for b in range(b_max):
        ips += ['1.92.168.{}.{}'.format(a,b)]
```

This will give you a list of all the IP addresses generated as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the addresses using `ip_address.split(.)` resulting in a `ip_list`. Keep track of the limit you have in mind. Increment each element of `ip_list` after converting to integer then convert back to string and put them all back together using `".".join(ip_list)`

Answer (score -1):

You can create a class with an `__add__` method:

```
class Ip:
 def __init__(self, _ip:str, _stop = 999) -> None:
   self.ip = _ip
   self.stop = _stop
 def __add__(self, _val):
   _ip = list(map(int, self.ip.split('.')))
   _r = 0
   while _r < 4:
     result = _ip[3 -_r]+_val
     if result < self.stop:
       _ip[3 - _r] += _val
       break
     _ip[3 - _r] += _val%self.stop
     _val = _val%self.stop
     _r += 1
     _ip[4 - _r] = 1
   return Ip('.'.join(map(str, _ip)))
 def __repr__(self):
   return f'<IP {self.ip}>'

p = Ip('192.168.1.1')
new_p = p + 1
print(new_p)
print(p + 1000)
```

Output:

```
<IP 192.168.1.2>
<IP 192.168.2.1>
```

Comment: Aye, that was me. You should not write a hacky `class Ip` for this stuff, when there is already a tried and tested one in the Python stdlibs:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address